# Able to connect to ssh server on any port using an ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh

I'm having a little problem with the ssh server running on an ubuntu server. I'm using key-pair authentication, and i'm able to connect just fine, but the problem is that i can connect on any port (using a tunnel), even though "Port 22" is defined in sshd_config. Why am i able to connect on any port? How can i stop ssh from listening to ports other than port 22?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I very much doubt it's listening on all ports. please show us the output of `netstat -ltpn`.

Comment: Ok, now i feel stupid. I can't connect directly using ssh on any port, but i'm able to connect using a tunnel. why is that?

Comment: @iedoc the output you show says that sshd listens on port 22 (on all IPv4 interfaces and all IPv6 interfaces). There's nothing here that says it listens on all ports.

Comment: I know, but if you look at the screenshot, i'm tunneling to remote port 80, and i'm able to connect to the ssh server. it seems that i can tunnel to any remote port and it will connect. i know i'm missing something, but what am i missing?

Comment: ok, so now i realize whats happening here. there are three ports in play, one of them is "implied". if i do -p 22, it works with the tunnel, but if i do -p 4321 or something, connection is refused. so to make sure i understand this tunneling thing, is the connection leaving the computer on "remote port" and connecting to the port defined after -p?

Comment: @iedoc the second screenshot shows you esablishing an ssh connection (which is to port 22), and then you create a tunnel listening on the local(of your windows machine) port 54321. TCP connections arriving at port 45321 of your windows machine is tunnelled over the SSH connection, and the other end (your ubuntu machine) will connect to 192.168.42.110(itself, that is) port 80. -p have nothing to do with tunnelling, -p specifies which port you want to establish the ssh connection to, which you must use if the ssh server is not listening on the default port 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot Local Address column tells that you are listening on all interfaces at port 22 (e.g. 0.0.0.0:22). The Foreign Address column tells that anyone can connect from any ip from any port (e.g 0.0.0.0:*). And below the same for IPV6.

The connections are normally started from some random free high number port so it's ok to have wildcard in Foreign address. The only thing you care about is that there is a listener at local port 22. Just as you wanted.

You are connecting the port 22 first (as you don't specify anything else with -p switch) and then ssh directs data from port 54321 of one machine to 80 of the other. So, the path of the data is something like:

Machine A, port 54321 -> Machine A, port random -> Machine B, port 22, Machine B, port 80.

Comment: The thing is, the devices that are connecting to this server are behind firewalls where we know port 22 is open for sure. I need to tunnel the connection so that it can make it through the firewall, which is why i'm using an ssh tunnel. In the screenshot above, i am tunneling to the remote port 80, and i'm still able to connect to the ssh server

Comment: ok thanks for the update. So basically, its like 2 tunnels? so it goes from port 54321 on the local machine to port 22 on the local machine, then from port 22 on the remote machine to port 80?

Comment: so if i do something like "4343:remotehost:4343", it will do something like "(4343->22)------>(22->4343)"?

Comment: More like (4343->23803)------>(22->4343).

Comment: I'll accept this, i was just confused a little with the "port random", but i got the idea now, thanks!

Comment: wait, now i'm confused! i need to make sure the connection leaves machine a on port 22 and enters machine b on port 22, because we only know that firewalls and routers are not blocking port 22

Comment: Mostly firewalls are not blocking connections going out from machines. If you have an ssh server running in both servers listening on port 22 as usual, you can't open the new ssh connection from that port as it's already taken by the ssh server process.

Comment: In the above example connection cannot be taken from the local port 4343 either as it will be also reserved by the sshd process for the tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is, when not defined, it will connect to the ssh server on the default port 22. you can explicitly define the port using "-p xxxx" where xxxx is the ssh server port you want to connect to. When tunneling, the "local port" is the port on your computer you will connect to, and "remote port" is the port on the remote computer that the connection will end on. so its like this:

(localport->randomport)->->->->(sshport->remoteport)

sshport is defined by -p, and the default when not defined is port 22